# Equivalent circuit of a three phase induction motor

Tags: induction-motor

So, i know that a equivalent circuit of a single phase of a three phase induction motor is just like a transformer equivalent circuit when it is at standstill. When, however, it is rotating the frequency dependent quantities like voltages, currents, reactants change as they should change. But, the thing with induction motor is, the input power and the output power, when rotating, are not same(because some power is given to the shaft) unlike transformer. In transformer i used this property to create equivalent circuit referred to primary side. Now, how can i further simplify the equivalent circuit of the three phase motor (equivalent circuit referred to stator). [image]

Answer (score 3):

> Now, how can i further simplify the equivalent circuit of the three
>   phase motor

Try this one: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IMEQCCT.jpg)

Comment: how can it be derived, can you please explain?

Comment: @QuaziMishkatulAlam you asked (in your question) how it could be simplified and not how it can be derived.

Comment: Try this: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEQQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnptel.ac.in%2Fcourses%2FIIT-MADRAS%2FElectrical_Machines_II%2Fpdf%2F1_5.pdf&ei=LQlzVPuNDcrnap7lgdgE&usg=AFQjCNEUiLC6G8v-C40zK-6776YfI_ES5w&bvm=bv.80185997,d.d2sei=FghzVJKoLsXgaLndgIAB&usg=AFQjCNEUiLC6G8v-C40zK-6776YfI_ES5w&bvm=bv.80185997,d.d2s&cad=rja

Comment: the link is not working...

Comment: It is from my end - just tried it. Search for "Electrical machines II by Prof. Krishna Vasudevan, Prof. G. Sridhara Rao, Prof. P. Sasidhara Rao" - its PDF is entitled "Theory of Synchronous Machines - nptel"